# Best way to return Error if Record Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some scripting in my Ruby on rails site to find a location and save a record to my database.

at the moment if the location is not found it returns Nil and still saves to database.

I would like it to error and continue on with the rest of the file parsing instead of saving nil values to the database.

Would modifing the database to NOT NIL on that column or is there a way to return Error if value is nil in coding

Something like the following

```
Begin
  SQL Query
rescue
  return error if Nil
end
```

model

```
class Hotload < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :log
  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:comments, :origin, :dest]}
  attr_accessible :comments, :covered, :delivery, :dest, :equipment_id, :length, :ltl, :origin, :pickup, :rate, :user_id, :weight, :source
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :equipment
  set_rgeo_factory_for_column(:origin, RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(:srid => 4326))
  set_rgeo_factory_for_column(:dest, RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(:srid => 4326))
  before_save :add_city_and_state
  has_one :company, through: :user

  def self.post(post)

    #convert the post to hash of strings
    post = post.stringify_keys    
    begin
      ['origin','dest'].each do |loc|
        state = post[loc][-2,2]
        city  = post[loc].gsub(%r(, [a-zA-Z]+), '').strip
        post[loc] = LocationFinder.call(city, state, "true")
      end
      post.keys.each do |key|
        if post[key] == ''
          post.delete(key)
        end
      end
      l = Hotload.where(:origin => post['origin'],:dest => post['dest'],:comments => post['comments']).first_or_create do |h|
        h.origin = post['origin']
        h.dest = post['dest']
        h.comments = post['comments']
        h.delivery = post['delivery']
        h.pickup = post['pickup']
        h.equipment_id = post['equipment_id']
        h.source = post['source']
        h.user_id = post['user_id']
        h.length  = post['length']
      end
      l.touch
      l.save # called so that we update the 'updated_at' field if we find the record above

    rescue Exception => e
      puts e unless Rails.env.test?
    end
  end
```

Helper

```
#takes in a city and state
# then looks in the database for the locations
# if they are not found, it attempts to find the location using Bing/Google
#
# Is_hotload is a placeholder that is used to determine how we report on unknown locations
#  if we get an unknown location, we try to add it immediately if it is a hotload
#    otherwise we only try to add it if it has been reported 10 times
#
# Returns either NIL or a POINT string representing the Location in the format "POINT (#{origin.coords.x} #{origin.coords.y})"

class LocationFinder

  def self.call(city, state, hotload)
    raise Error if [city,state].include? nil
    LocationFinder.new(city, state, hotload).find_location
  end

  attr_accessor :city, :state, :hotload, :lat, :lng

  def initialize(city, state, hotload)
    @city  =  city.to_s.try(:downcase)
    @state = state.to_s.try(:downcase)
    @hotload = hotload

  end

  # for testing purposes only
  # @lat = "37.208969116210938"
   # @lng = "-93.291557312011719"



  def find_location
    location = validate_location
    location ||= search_database
    location ||= search_levenshtein
    location ||= search_unknown
    unless location.nil? || location.empty?
      location.try(:coords)
    end
  end

  def validate_location
    [city,state].each do |val|
      return "ANYWHERE" if val.blank?
      return "ANYWHERE" if val.upcase == "ANYWHERE"
    end
    # if city =~ /\d{5}/
    #   city =
    # end
    nil
  end

  def search_database
    Location.first(:conditions => {:city => city, :state => state})
  end

  def search_levenshtein
    Location.where("(levenshtein(city, '#{city}') <= 4) AND state = '#{state}'").order("levenshtein(city, '#{city}') ASC").first
  end

  # Tries to find the location using an external API if it
  #  have a value greater than 10 or is a hotload
  def search_unknown
    cs = "#{city}, #{state}"
    Report.check_and_add('unknown_locations', cs) unless hotload == "true"
    report = Report.first( :conditions => { :metric => "unknown_locations", :name => cs } )
    if report.value > 10 || hotload == "true"
      begin
        parse_geo_data
        l = location_insert
        if Location.city_state_exists?("#{city}, #{state}")
          Report.delete(report.id)
        end
      rescue => detail
        Report.new( {:name => cs, :metric => "Could Not Add", :value => '1', :reason => detail.to_s} ).save
      end
    end
  end


  def parse_geo_data
    cs = "#{city}, #{state}"
    puts cs
    google_api_results = HTTParty.get("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/#{cs.gsub(/ /, "%20")}?o=xml&key=AvtYnvs3UjKaIPdG5v1YaVBL_5-Rhg_zgUwoQgvTiTS9dMxJSreIanWVLvTzQc86")
    geo_data = google_api_results.parsed_response
    lat = geo_data["Response"]["ResourceSets"]["ResourceSet"]["Resources"]["Location"]["Point"]["Latitude"]
    lng = geo_data["Response"]["ResourceSets"]["ResourceSet"]["Resources"]["Location"]["Point"]["Longitude"]
    name = geo_data["Response"]["ResourceSets"]["ResourceSet"]["Resources"]["Location"]["Name"]
    city, state = name.downcase.split(",")
    state = state.strip
    self.lat = lat
    self.lng = lng
    self.city = city
    self.state = state

  end

  def location_insert
    Location.create({:city => city, :state => state, :coords => "POINT(#{lng.to_f} #{lat.to_f})", :cs => "#{city}, #{state}"})
  end


end
```

Comment: you have the code for finding the location in model or controller?

Comment: Do you have any validation on your relevant models to catch the not-founds?  What does your model look like?

Comment: it is in my model and is pretty extensive... I have it checking for exact spelling then levenshtein spelling then tring to add it to database from outside database... but if stil not found would like it to error out

Comment: Added model and helper above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a presence validation to your model will keep the "bad" data from being saved:

```
validates :origin, :dest, :presence => true
```

You'll have the error messages available through `l.errors` in your `post` method. If you return `l`, then your calling code can [reference those errors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors) for display or logging.

Comment: thanks.... sometimes the simplest things can be the solution... that helps with that issue